# Is there a regulation against having uncaged dogs or other animals as passengers on private aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations

There is flight club at our field and this discussion came up.  A regulation cited would settle the matter.

Comment: In [low gravity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NvBGb5lf78)

Comment: Interesting article: [Flying with Your Furry Friend](http://www.flyingmag.com/technique/tip-week/flying-your-furry-friend)

Comment: [CFR 91.13 Careless or reckless operation](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13) might apply under certain circumstances

Comment: FWIW, there's a difference between "uncaged" and "unrestrained". It's fairly common for to use a seat belt harness to limit a dog to the back seat but allow it some movement. I've never seen a specific regulation on this, but of course 91.13 is always there if the dog causes a problem. You might find the [Pilots N Paws pilot guidelines](https://www.pilotsnpaws.org/guidelines/guidelines-for-pilots/) useful.

Comment: Animals should be crated for the same reason passengers should be belted and all cargo properly stowed - in the event things go sideways, any loose item becomes a missile and can cause serious injury (of course, this assumes the crate is secured somehow; if it isn't, then it's no better than leaving the animal uncrated).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that the answer is "there is no such regulation". For example, from AOPA's [Flying with Family](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/active-pilots/safety-and-technique/operations/flying-with-family):

> Airlines require that any animal on board be confined to an animal carrier at all times. Although there are no such requirements for general aviation aircraft, it is always better to err on the side of safety and keep them in a carrier.

Comment: Doesn't that lack of regulation compromise Part 91 section 107 that requires seat belts on all passengers?

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty: [Section 107](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=3b61b62546776eea1012cd2d8e5b201b&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1107&rgn=div8) refers to the use of safety belts by *persons* on board. I don't think animals qualify as persons for the purposes of the FAA regulations.

Comment: as in motor vehicles, I sense a disregard for animal passenger safety.

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty: I'm pretty sure the cages we get here are not safer than no cage; but then again I've seen some people ridiculously mishandle their dogs. In addition, the dog just doesn't understand why he needs to be strapped down.